# In logistic regression model in Python, how to treat multicollinearity

Tags: python, logistic-regression, correlation, p-value, multicollinearity

In logistic regression model in Python, how to treat multicollinearity in Python in logistic regression model. What do we do when there are high correlated variables from a correlation matrix. Suggest me python steps to reduce multicollinearity

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try regularization. It will add an additional constraint on the weight vector and you can handle multicollinearity. This limit can be set in different ways, but, as a rule, you don't need something more complicated, than [L1 or L2 regularization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regularization-in-machine-learning/).
2. Try to reduce dimensions of your df with [Factor Analysis](https://medium.com/@hongwy1128/intro-guide-to-factor-analysis-python-84dd0b0fd729). As a result you will get a dataframe of not-correlated factors, wich generally describe the full set of your features.